# Time is not formatting correctly

Tags: momentjs, angular-moment

I have this this date

```
    <p am-time-ago="Thu Oct 15 21:53:55 IST 2015"></p>
```

it shows 
`[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Oct' is an unexpected token at column 5 of the expression [Thu Oct 15 21:53:55 IST 2015] starting at [Oct 15 21:53:55 IST 2015].`

`2015-10-13T18:49:52.888Z`

it shows `Token 'T18' is an unexpected token at column 11 of the expression [2015-10-13T18:49:52.888Z] starting at [T18:49:52.888Z].`

Answer (score 0):

Moment isn't parsing the date correctly because it is in an unsupported format.

For the first one, change IST to the offset (+05:30).

For the second, get rid of the T and Z, and put a space between the date and time.

Edit: Note that more recent versions of moment js don't support TZ abbreviations anymore, like IST or CST or UTC. That function was deprecated in 1.6.0.

Comment: i think this is kind of bug in moment.js cos `timeago` plugin parse `2015-10-13T18:49:52.888Z` format

Comment: That's a possibility, the former is due to (relatively) recent changes to the parser that deprecated the TZ abbreviation format (e.g, IST, CST).